# How to simulate "Start Sync" button in a test?

Tags: apex, unit-test

This is not the first time I have this issue. When I need to simulate a Quote being synced in a test, I use the following code:

```
opportunity.SyncedQuoteId = quote.Id;
update opportunity;
```

But again I have a different behavior in the test than when using regular interface for this operation. This time I have the test failing with the below error:

> first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, cannot change pricebook: []

That `update opportunity` command fails with that error, but doing the same actions via interface works (create opp, create quote, add an item, sync quote). So I'm guessing updating the SyncedQuoteId field is not enough.

The whole point of testing is to reproduce the user behavior and asserting the desired output and actions will happen as expected. But the "Start Sync" button behavior is a mistery to me, I don't know what exactly it does. Apparently something more than just updating the Opportunity's SyncedQuoteId field.

So, how can I programmatically reproduce the "Start Sync" button? Which series os steps should I be doing in tests to have the same behavior of the user interface?

Comment: The only problem here, is that your opportunity and your quote has not the same pricebook2Id. It will work after that.

Comment: The opportunity is expected to have no pricebook at this point, I am precisely syncing the first quote which should be syncing the pricebook selected in the quote to the opportunity. My problem here is that I get different behaviors when doing that via Apex code or via interface. Or do you mean that I should explicitly do an `opportunity.Pricebook2Id = pricebook.Id;` before setting the synced quote id? Is that what the button does when used via interface?